# Prove $\sin x=3x-2$ has only one real solution

Tags: proof-writing

Obviously you can draw a graph, but how would you prove this with calculus?

Comment: Differentiate $3x-2-\sin x$. See that the derivative is always positive. Having two different roots would violate the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: When is the RHS inside the image $\sin(\mathbb R)$? How does $\sin$ behave there? EDIT: Henning's answer is more straight-forward.

Comment: And having no roots at all would violate the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Since $|\sin'(x)| \le 1$ you have $|\sin x_1 - \sin x_2| \le |x_1 -x_2|$.

Suppose $x_1, x_2$ satisfy the given equation. Then
$|\sin x_1 - \sin x_2| = 3 |x_1-x_2|$ and the only way
$3 |x_1-x_2| \le |x_1 -x_2|$ can be satisfied is if $x_1 = x_2$.

As an aside, if we let $\phi(x) = {1 \over 3} (\sin x +2)$, we see that $x$ solves the equation **iff** $\phi(x) = x$. Note that $|\phi'(x)| \le {1 \over 3}$, hence $\phi$ is a contraction map and has a unique solution which can be found by iterating $x_{n+1} = \phi(x_n)$.